# Want to retrieve columns based on common name ending in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file that I'm trying to analyze in R.

I want to retrieve the information from certain columns in which the names have a common ending ('DOM') and store it as an object:

domaincolumns <- MyData[,c()]

Does anyone know how I could go about this?

Comment: You can use base R's `endsWith`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` or `grepl`:

`domaincolumns <- MyData[,grepl(pattern = "DOM$", colnames(MyData))]`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `select` from `dplyr`

```
domaincolums <- MyData %>% select (ends_with("DOM"))
```

Comment: @user20650 You are right. I overlooked 'ends with' in the posted question. Although this might still give you the result you need.